# Java Task Execution and Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, task

I am having the code this way..

1) Invoking the updatedb method using reflection...

```
for (String uniqueSym : activeSymbolsSet) {
    futureTaskUtil.submiteTask(new Helper(),
    Helper.class.getDeclaredMethod("updateDb", 
           new Class<?>[] { String.class }), new Object[] { uniqueSym }, 60);
}
```

**- futureTaskUtil:**

2) My question is this updatedb is executed as an run time task...

```
public Object submiteTask(final Object obj, final Method method, final Object[] params, int timeoutSeconds) throws Exception {
    if (null != obj && method != null) {
        Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
        public Object call() {
            try {
                method.setAccessible(true);
                Object resultObj = method.invoke(obj, params);
                return resultObj;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.fatal("Exception occured while invoking future task.", e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);
    try {
        Object result = null;
        if (timeoutSeconds < 0) {
            result = future.get(timoutsec, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } else {
            result = future.get(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        logger.info("Result of method execution is  :: " + result);
        return result;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.fatal("Exception occured while executing future tas : " + obj, e);
    } finally {
        future.cancel(true); // may or may not desire this
    }
}
return null;
}
```

can some one explain why this is executed as an seperate task and invoking the method?

Comment: You want us to explain why it works as it should? IMHO its a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);` This is your culprit You can read about Executer Framework [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)

Answer (score 0):

What if the method never returns? Then the application would hang at this point.
Using this wrapper, the method will be canceled after 60 seconds.